# Best way to build a "select all" checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a "select all" checkbox(A) and some others related to it(B).

I hope:

1. When A's checked or not, make all of B the same as A.
2. When all of B's checked, make A's checked.
3. When not all of B's checked,make A's not checked.

Using JQuery is preferred, **but is there a better way coming with HTML5?**

like:

```
<checkbox id="target" name="select all"/>
<checkbox relatetd="target" name="1"/>
<checkbox relatetd="target" name="2"/>
```

Or something like xpath if I have many subgroups with **DIFFERENT** DOM structures:

```
<checkbox id="target" name="select all"/>
<div>
    <checkbox relatetd="../" name="1"/>
    <checkbox relatetd="../" name="2"/>
</div>

<checkbox id="target2" name="select all"/>
<div>
    <div>
        <checkbox relatetd="../../" name="1"/>
        <checkbox relatetd="../../" name="2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" /> Check / Uncheck All

<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option1" /> Option 1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option2" /> Option 2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="option3" /> Option 3




$('#checkAll').change(function () {
    $('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$(".chk").change(function () {
    if ($(".chk:checked").length == $(".chk").length) {
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('#checkAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7BXJF/1/)

This should work for you

Comment: Thank you, It does work! But I'll have to prepare a lot of different css classes if there're many subgourps.

Comment: Hey, for this you can look at this code sample http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/150/ may work for you, If your problem got fixed, can you please mark my solution as correct

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

simply add `data-parent="< value of the parent >"` to any child `checkbox` like:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A"> <b>Option A</b>
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="A1" data-parent="A"> Option A.1
</label>
```

[**JsBin DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/opexof/1/edit) has all the code: http://jsbin.com/opexof/1

---

The demo script is commented out so you can see what's going on, but the general idea is:

- check if it's children or parent
- if children, see how many brothers exist and compare with how many brothers are checked

  - if the numbers match, select it's parent
  - if not, unselected
- if it's a parent, select all children or not depending if you are selecting or unselecting the parent.

Hope it works.

Comment: Nice, but in some complex scenario, every subgroups have different DOM structures. How can I keep the js code reusable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clear way, 4 css classes for checkboxes:

- `family`,`parent`,`child` for relationship,
- and `invalid` for status.

Checking `parent` means **select all** valid checkboxes in a family.
It supports nested families.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/doraeimo/c4K4E/

```
<fieldset class="family" >
<legend>big_family</legend>
<label>select all
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" name="select_all"/>
</label>

<fieldset class="family">
    <legend>sub_family_1</legend>
    <label>select all
        <input type="checkbox" class="parent"/>
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child invalid"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="family">
    <legend>sub_family_2</legend>
    <label> select all
        <input type="checkbox" class="parent"/>
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child invalid"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems as if you have your answer, but i'll give you another variation just in case:

```
//Fill in all check marks for the Copy Feature when "select all" is chosen
$('#all').click(function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"][id^="copy_"]'),function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', isChecked);
    })
    if (isChecked){
        $('#labelAll').html('Unselect All');
    }else{
        $('#labelAll').html('Select All');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8RmJ/)

Comment: Sorry,it's not satisfied requirement 3. Thank you all the same!